# Create a menu based on taxonomy terms, first level being a drop down select, last level being the content type

Tags: 7

Fairly new to Drupal. I made some sites in D6 ages ago and D7 is totally new to me.

I'm about to do a small site with a hierarchical menu where the visitor can put items from the different markets/categories in a cart to checkout.

The menu should consist of a dropdown select where the user first selects the market of his choice.
Underneath it there should be a menu listing of categories and subcategories like this:

[Market] (drop down menu with a lite of countries)

-- Product catergory 1 (submenu expanded by default)
----- Banners (this submenu opens a page that lists content of type "banner" for selected market/prod.category)
----- Events
----- Campaign sites
-- Product catergory 2
-- Product catergory 3
-- Product catergory 4
I'm not sure how to go about doing this. I was thinking making 2 taxonomy vocabularies.
Markets is one vocabulary listing a couple of countries.

And then another vocabulary named Products, listing the different product categories.

When I create a new content type I first mark it with one or more markets it's available in. And also what product category it belongs to. The content itself is of the type shown in the menu example above (banner, event, capaign site or whatever).

Maybe this all can be done in views or multiple blocks or something, suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if i got you right and what you try to do exactly, but check out the "Hierarchical Select" module, probably this might help you.

Comment: Thanks, i looked at the module suggested but i think it might not be enough.. I've updated my question with some more details.